# VNC connection stops updating after a short period

Tags: vnc

So I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a [5" screen](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1784.html) that's too small to do dev work on so I want to be able to VNC in with a larger resolution virtual desktop. And in fact it works out of the box with the Real VNC server that comes with Raspbian. The problem is that after 5 second to a few minutes the VNC connection stops updating the screen. The clicks are still being sent, but nothing changes. If I re-connect I can see the updated screen. For a few seconds to minutes then it dies again.

Things I've tried:

- Mac RealVNC client -> Pi RealVNC Server = stops updating (SU)
- Mac Screen Sharing -> Pi RealVNC Server = won't connect (WC)
- Mac TigerVNC client -> Pi RealVNC Server = SU
- Mac RealVNC client -> Pi TightVNC Server = SU
- Mac TightVNC client -> Pi TightVNC Server = SU
- Windows RealVNC client -> Pi RealVNC Server = SU
- Windows TightVNC client -> Pi RealVNC Server = SU
- Windows RealVNC client -> Pi TightVNC Server = SU
- Windows TightVNC client -> Pi TightVNC Server = SU..

I've enumerated a bunch options there ;)

There is no [NoMachine client](https://www.nomachine.com/) for ARM... boo.

There is no messages in the ~/.vnc/log.. files when the screen stops updating.

If I disconnect the local screen and run totally headless it works fine. So something about having the local screen attached is breaking VNC. But I have no idea what.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use VNC a lot (not with the Pi).
You had to constantly restart the VNC application/screen to be able try and connect again and after about 5 minutes it was often successful.

Comment: With the screen attach reconnecting always works for me. But only gives me 5-10 seconds (typical) of usage before stalling again.  Without the screen attached I used VNC for over an hour with no problems. Which is what I need... continuous access without update stalls.